# Can I get Unix timestamp automatically converted to a DATETIME column when importing from CSV to a (My)SQL database?

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime, unix-timestamp

I created a table that has a `timestamp DATETIME` column and I am trying to import data from `CSV` files that have Unix timestamped rows.

However, when I try to use DataGrip's CSV import feature, I get errors to the tune of

```
1:1: conversion failed: "1394669640" to datetime
2:1: conversion failed: "1394670060" to datetime
3:1: conversion failed: "1394670480" to datetime
4:1: conversion failed: "1394670780" to datetime
```

Maybe dataGrip is not the best tool, but that's pretty much all I can do with, given that I don't have direct access to the machine which runs the DB server[*]. Obviously this works if I set the column to be `INT`.

Is there a way of configuring the table so that the conversion happens automatically?

---

[*] I do, but the DBMS is running inside a Docker container so, short of copying the CSV files on the host and then inside the container, I can't play tricks like `LOAD DATA INFILE` and set the column with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to load a CSV file to a remote MySQL (i.e. inside a docker container), without needing to copy the CSV file into the container.

```
mysql> create table MyTable (timestamp DATETIME PRIMARY KEY);

mysql> load data local infile 'data.csv' into table MyTable (@dummy) 
    SET timestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(@dummy);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from MyTable;
+---------------------+
| timestamp           |
+---------------------+
| 2014-03-13 00:14:00 |
| 2014-03-13 00:21:00 |
| 2014-03-13 00:28:00 |
| 2014-03-13 00:33:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Note the `local-infile` option needs to be enabled both on your server, to allow remote clients, and also in the client. To do the example above, I had to enable `local-infile=1` in my server's `/etc/my.cnf` and I also ran the client with the option `mysql --local-infile`. Without both of those options, I got this very confusing error:

*ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version*

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html for details.