# Can I get Unix timestamp automatically converted to a TIMESTAMP column when importing from CSV to a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, csv, timestamp

This is basically a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945505/can-i-get-unix-timestamp-automatically-converted-to-a-datetime-column-when-impor) with `s/mysql/postgresql/g`.

---

I created a table that has a `timestamp TIMESTAMP` column and I am trying to import data from `CSV` files that have Unix timestamped rows.

However, when I try to `COPY` the file into the table, I get errors to the tune of

```
2:1: conversion failed: "1394755260" to timestamp
3:1: conversion failed: "1394755320" to timestamp
4:1: conversion failed: "1394755800" to timestamp
5:1: conversion failed: "1394755920" to timestamp
```

Obviously this works if I set the column to be `INT`.

In the MySQL variant, I solved with a trick like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE raw_data
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
 (@timestamp, other_column)
SET timestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(@timestamp),
    third_column = 'SomeSpecialValue'
;
```

Note two things: I can map the `@timestamp` variable from the CSV file using a function to turn it into a proper `DATETIME`, and I can set extra columns to certain values (this is necessary because I have more columns in the database than in the CSV).

I'm switching to postgresql because mysql lacks some functions that make my life so much easier with the queries I need to write.

Is there a way of configuring the table so that the conversion happens automatically?

Comment: Is this a one-time import? In that case, define the column as `bigint`, import the data, then convert the column to a proper `timestamp`

Comment: I plan to add data further on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this by importing the data as-is, creating a second column with the converted timestamp and then using a trigger to make sure any time a row is inserted it populates the new column:

```
alter table raw_table
add column time_stamp timestamp;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raw_table_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.time_stamp = timestamp 'epoch' + NEW.unix_time_stamp * interval '1 second';
  return NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_raw_table_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON raw_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE raw_table_insert();
```

If the timestamp column can be modified, then you will want to make sure the trigger applies to updates as well.

Alternatively, you can create a view that generates the timestamp on the fly, but the advantages/disadvantages depend on how often you search on the column,  how large the table is going to be and how much DML you expect.